# statistics questions.. i know the method for finding median but this is different

Tags: statistics

find the median of the following data 18,37,24,59,41,63,45,57,29. In the above data, if 37 is replaced by 73 find the new median

Comment: How is it 'different'?

Comment: read the notion more carefully

Comment: It is a good idea to use the body of the Question to frame the problem in a self-contained way (not relying on the title to bear this burden).  In many cases the effort to give a good problem statement will lead you to solving the problem yourself with little additional work.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the data in ascending order. Determine the number of data points ($n$). If $n$ is odd (as in this case), it's easy, just take the $\frac{n+1} {2} $th element in the sorted list, that's the median.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 37 by 73 then follow the procedure by @Deepak and you will get the median as 45.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The median is the element of rank $5$.

$37$ has rank $4$, as there are $3$ smaller elements, so it is smaller than the median.

$73$ will have the rank $9$ as it is the largest of all, and this is above the median.

Hence you can say that after performing the replacement, the median becomes the element of rank $6$ in the initial array.

Answer (score 0):

First thing arrange terms in increasing.

Median in case if we have given odd number of terms is value at $\frac{n+1}{2}$

Median in case if we have given even number of is  values at $\frac{\frac{n}{2} + \left( \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right)}{2}$

n is number of terms.

> In your case first replace 37 by 73 then arrange in increasing order.

18, 24, 29, 41, 45, 57, 59, 63, 73

We have n = 9 (odd) terms.

So median is value at $\frac{9 + 1}{2}$

Value at 5th place. So answer is 45.